# Lauterbach execute script when breakpoint is hit

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I am using Lauterbach to debug a PowerPC embedded C software. I want to execute the below ALGO from a .cmm(PRACTICE) script. Pleas let me know if it is possible:

```
Set Breakpoint
When Breakpoint is hit, execute a .cmm file. This .cmm file will rewrite the values of an array.
Continue execution of program
```

I don't want to stub the whole function. The code has to be untouched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the breakpoint with

```
   Break.Set <addr> /Program /CMD "DO myScript.cmm"
```

To continue the execution of the target program, add the command `Go` to the end of the called PRACTICE script.

If you can't add the command `Go` to the end of the called PRACTICE script, you'll need a veneer-script like this:

```
// Content of myScript.cmm
DO myAlgorithm.cmm
Go
ENDDO
```

The `Break.Set` command knows also an option `/RESUME`, but this is not suitable for your case, since it won't wait until the called PRACTICE script has finished.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned !

> I don't want to stub the whole function. The code has to be untouched.

You can try this;

```
;set a breakpoint on function
BREAK.SET <function_name/addr>\<LINE NUMBER>

;store address of current program counter(PC)
&pc=r(pc)

&call=address.offset(<function_name/addr>\<LINE NUMBER>) ;This will give the address of a function where breakpoint is set.

;Compare the address if it hit on correct function 
IF (&pc==&call)
    Do call_meonceHIT.cmm ;your desired .cmm script.
Break.Delete /ALL ; to delete all the set breakpoint.
```

This will make sure that breakpoint is hitting correct function or runnable.